# How to use grails GORM to do left outer join with multiple field matches?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

We have a need to do the following with our grails project:

```
select * from message m  
LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.message_id = m.id and v.user_id = 1 
where parent_id is null;
```

The domain classes are fairly simple:

```
class Message {

    String text
    User user

    static belongsTo = [parent:Message]

    static hasMany = [messages:Message, votes:Votes]

    static constraints = {
        parent nullable: true
    }

    static mapping = {
        votes lazy: false
    }
}

class Votes {

    User user
    Message message
    int vote = 0

    static belongsTo = [user:User, message:Message]

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
        vote defaultValue: 0
    }
}
```

So far we were able to get `v.message_id = m.id` condition to work but unable to add `and v.user_id = 1` condition to the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Here is the Controller code:

```
    def test = Message.withCriteria {

        isNull('parent')
        createAlias('votes', 'v', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)

    }
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

We figured it out, the right code is

```
def test = Message.withCriteria {
        isNull('parent')        
        createAlias('votes', 'v', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN,   Restrictions.eq("v.user.id", 1 as long));
    }
```

This generate SQL query exactly as needed.

Comment: This buried answer with 0 votes was extremely helpful for me!  To add to it, Restrictions can be quite complex with the use of `Restrictions.and`, `Restrictions.or`, etc.  I'm using the `and` method with great results, passing in two additional `Restrictions`.  As noted, the field provided (ex: 'v.user.id') can be drilled down further than usually allowed in criteria builders.

Comment: If anyone looking for conditional left join/left outer join then this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

why can't you just use the second condition in reqular eq restriction? your sql is the same as: `select * from message m LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.message_id = m.id where parent_id is null and v.user_id = 1;`

```
def test = Message.withCriteria {
    isNull('parent')
    createAlias('votes', 'v', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    eq 'v.user', User.get(1)
}
```

or else

```
def test = Message.withCriteria {
    isNull('parent')
    createAlias('votes', 'v', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    createAlias('v.user', 'u', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
    eq 'u.id', 1
}
```

Comment: First example will put match condition after "WHERE", second example, will create second LEFT OUTER JOIN, neither that I want.

Comment: Having matches after WHERE will negate the function of LEFT OUTER JOIN and cause result set to be filtered by v.user_id = 1

Answer (score 0):

**For anyone working with Grails 3**

```
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions

...
...

def test = Message.withCriteria {
        isNull('parent')        
        createAlias('votes', 'v', JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN, Restrictions.eq("v.user.id", 1 as long));
    }
```